# Python Selenium: Unable to click button

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm new to python and want to write a web scraper which involves mouse clicking an "OK" button on a pop-up window.

Everything else went well but I'm not able to click the final button which leads to the data downloading.

The javascript is as follows:

[image]

I tried finding element by id but the following error message appeared:

[image]

Comment: You know, instead of using Screenshots of the code, use your previous version in which you had actually added the code. This will get you downvotes

Comment: @NSNoob. Cool it's my first time to post anything. thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

`find_elements_by_id` returns a list of elements. Either iterate over the list that `find_elements_by_id` returns or use `find_element_by_id` (notice the missing 's') which will return only a single element (if any).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
browser.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ContentContainer1_ctl00_ButtonsContent_ExportOptionsBottomButtons_OkLabel').click()
```

Changed this:

```
find_elements_by_id
```

to this:

```
find_element_by_id
```